# Dialog box shows when spacebar is hit in datatable of Primefaces6.0,

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, dialog

I am facing an issue with modal(dialog box) in Primefaces6.0. I have a simple datatable with multiple selection mode. Datatable also has a input text component and on rowselect event, a dialogbox populates displaying more information with respect to the row. The issue here is when I first click on the datatable row, dialog box appear(that is how it is supposed to work). Now close the dialog and start typing in its respective input text component and hit spacebar, dialogbox appears(this is the actual bug). **This issue exists only in Primefaces6.0 and same code is working fine in Primefaces5.3** release. Since responsive/resizing of datatable and other components is possible in Primefaces6.0, I have to stick to it and cannot go with the other one. Please help me in solving my issue.

Code samples are below:-

index.xhtml

```
    <p:dataTable id="dtEmployee" value="#{mbEmployee.lstEmployee}" var="emp" selection="#{mbEmployee.lstSelectedEmp}" rowKey="#{emp.regNo}">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":frmEmployee:diShow" oncomplete="PF('dgInfo').show();"/>

        <p:column headerText="Employee No">
            <h:outputText id="lblReNo" value="#{emp.regNo}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Employee Name">
            <h:outputText id="lblEmpName" value="#{emp.employeeName}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Employee City">
            <h:outputText id="lblCity" value="#{emp.city}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Feedback">
            <p:inputText id="txtFeedback" value="#{mbEmployee.feedback}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Select" selectionMode="multiple" style="text-align: center"/>
    </p:dataTable>



    <p:dialog id="diShow" modal="true" widgetVar="dgInfo" closable="true">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel id="DispRegNo" value="Reg No"/>
            <p:outputLabel id="lblDispRegNo" value="#{mbEmployee.lstSelectedEmp[0].regNo} "/>
            <p:outputLabel id="DispName" value="Employee Name"/>
            <p:outputLabel id="lblDispName" value="#{mbEmployee.lstSelectedEmp[0].employeeName}"/>
            <p:outputLabel id="DispCity" value="City"/>
            <p:outputLabel id="lblDispCity" value="#{mbEmployee.lstSelectedEmp[0].city}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
```

java class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mbEmployee", eager = true)

public class employee {
    private List<employeeBean> lstEmployee;
    private List<employeeBean> lstSelectedEmp;
    private String feedback;

    public String getFeedback() {
        return feedback;
    }

    public void setFeedback(String feedback) {
        this.feedback = feedback;
    }

    public List<employeeBean> getLstEmployee() {
        return lstEmployee;
    }

    public void setLstEmployee(List<employeeBean> lstEmployee) {
        this.lstEmployee = lstEmployee;
    }

    public List<employeeBean> getLstSelectedEmp() {
        return lstSelectedEmp;
    }

    public void setLstSelectedEmp(List<employeeBean> lstSelectedEmp) {
        this.lstSelectedEmp = lstSelectedEmp;
    }

    public employee() {
        lstEmployee = new ArrayList<>();
        lstEmployee.add(new employeeBean("ABC", "XYZ", 45, 1001));
        lstEmployee.add(new employeeBean("DEF", "XYZ", 45, 1002));
        lstEmployee.add(new employeeBean("GHI", "XYZ", 45, 1003));
        lstEmployee.add(new employeeBean("JKL", "XYZ", 45, 1004));
        lstEmployee.add(new employeeBean("MNO", "XYZ", 45, 1005));
    }
}
```

bean class:

```
public class employeeBean {

    private String employeeName, city, feedback;
    private int age, regNo;

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getFeedback() {
        return feedback;
    }

    public void setFeedback(String feedback) {
        this.feedback = feedback;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getRegNo() {
        return regNo;
    }

    public void setRegNo(int regNo) {
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }

    public employeeBean(String employeeName, String city, String feedback, int age, int regNo) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.city = city;
        this.feedback = feedback;
        this.age = age;
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }

    public employeeBean(String employeeName, String city, int age, int regNo) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any error exists in the code or any hack to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you right: as I can read about it this is an open issue. Well my solution for this issue is very simple

1. Add a class like "in" to inputText

   ```
   <p:inputText styleClass="in" value="#{mbEmployee.feedback}" />
   ```
2. Use JQuery for stop the event propagation (parent stop)

   ```
   $(document).on("ready", function(){ 

       $(".in").keydown(function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
       });
   });
   ```
3. Check this sample
   [image: Easy way]

**Please Note:** I was removed the id from your inputText tag. Don't forget that the value of "mbEmployee.feedBack" is single for all inputText tags.

I hope this useful! Regards!

Comment: Where did you read it is can open issue? Care to add a link to it?